# if Statement not finiding variable when inside function (Wordpress Plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, if-statement

The variable is not accessable inside the funtion.
When I echo the variable outside the function I get the correct result. When I echo/use the variable inside the function I get a 'Notice: Undefined variable: crLocalIncompleteStatus in /setup.php on line 35'

Any ideas?

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'crLocal';

    $crLocalIncompleteStatus = '';
    $crLocalCompleteStatus = '';

    $crLocal_DBChecked = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name");

    function crLocal_CheckDB() {
        global $crLocal_DBChecked,  $crLocalIncompleteStatus, $crLocalCompleteStatus;

        if ($crLocal_DBChecked == '0') { 
            $crLocalIncompleteStatus = 'block' ;
            $crLocalCompleteStatus = 'none' ;
        } elseif ($crLocal_DBChecked != '0') { 
            $crLocalIncompleteStatus = 'none' ;
            $crLocalCompleteStatus = 'block' ;
        } else {
            // Broken
            // More Code to follow
        }

        echo $crLocal_DBChecked;
    }

    crLocal_CheckDB();

    $crLocalInstallIncomplete = '<div id="crLocalInstallIncomplete" style="display: '.$crLocalIncompleteStatus.';">' ;

    $crLocalInstallComplete = '<div id="crLocalInstallComplete" style="display: '.$crLocalCompleteStatus.';">' ;

?>
```

So I need:

$crLocalIncompleteStatus to be 'block' when the count is 0 from the database and 'none' when its above 0.

$crLocalCompleteStatus to be 'none' when the count is 0 from the database and 'block' when its above 0.

Comment: Any reason why you would want to use global in this place to begin with, instead of properly passing the values the function needs access to as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your variable $crLocalIncompleteStatus is outside of your function's scope, you can correct this by adding the variable to the function as a parameter

```
function crLocal_CheckDB($crLocalIncompleteStatus) {
    global $crLocal_DBChecked,  $crLocalIncompleteStatus, $crLocalCompleteStatus;

    if ($crLocal_DBChecked == '0') { 
        $crLocalIncompleteStatus = 'block' ;
        $crLocalCompleteStatus = 'none' ;
    } elseif ($crLocal_DBChecked != '0') { 
        $crLocalIncompleteStatus = 'none' ;
        $crLocalCompleteStatus = 'block' ;
    } else {
        // Broken
        // More Code to follow
    }

    echo $crLocal_DBChecked;
}

crLocal_CheckDB($crLocalIncompleteStatus);
```